# angular ng-repeat prefilter in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have the following angular js filter `ng-repeat` on a tr element.  How could I accomplish all of this in javascript?  Would it be possible to do it in one custom filter?

NOTE: showRow is a function that returns a bool, search string is a string

```
ng-repeat="lob in filtered = (lobs | filter : showRow | filter : searchString | orderBy : 'name':true )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $filter service, or $scope.$eval:

```
$filter('orderBy')(
    $filter('filter')(
        $filter('filter')($scope.lobs, $scope.showRow),
    $scope.searchString),
'name', true);

$scope.$eval("lobs | filter : showRow | filter : searchString | orderBy : 'name':true");
```

Not tested, but should be close enough to work.

And yes, using the first way, you could create your own filter that does all that.

Answer (score 1):

Code would be like below

```
var firstFilter = $filter('filter')($scope.lobs, $scope.showRow)
var secondFilter = $filter('filter')(firstFilter , $scope.searchString)
var finalFilter = $filter('orderBy')(secondFilter , 'name', true)
```

Don't forget to add `$filter` dependency on controller